# FontAwesome: css content: "\f468"; doesnt work for some

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5, font-awesome-4

I am using the following method to display icons

```
&:before {
  font-family: Fontawesome;
  content: "\f468";
}
```

that works for about 30% of the icons. For example I tried the above, `f468` and that did not work but when i did `<i class="fas fa-boxes"></i>` the icon displayed. Can you see the problem?

Im using https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css

Answer (score 1):

In the Font Awesome stylesheet, `.fas{}` has `font-weight: 900;` Many icons will show alternate versions or no icon at all if you do not include this.

```
&:before {
  font-family: Fontawesome;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f468";
}
```

See if this code works for you.

Comment: changing the font-weight did not work. Maybe we are writing the `font-fam` wrong?  It may also have something to do with `fas` vc `fa`

Comment: try `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";` example works for me with f468

Comment: The font-family is wrong. qfazille shows the font family that fontawesome ues in their code.The easiest way for you to figure this out is to inspect the working fa-boxes code and see what it uses differently.

I had assumed based on your use of "Fontawesome" as the font-family that you may have downloaded the font and renamed it.

If changing the `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"` doesn't work, please give us a demo with more information - the stylesheet link you use for example.